# What is HWND in VC++

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++

What is the equivalent of HWND(VC++) in C#? I want to send HWND from my C# program to the VC++ dll.

Answer (score 14):

HWND is a "handle to a window" and is part of the Win32 API . HWNDs are essentially pointers (IntPtr) with values that make them (sort of) point to a window-structure data. In general HWNDs are part an example for applying the [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) model.

If you want a Control's HWND see [Control.Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) property. It is an IntPtr which value is an HWND.

Since HWND are not a .Net entity, they need to be released manually. This is done with [Control.DestroyHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.destroyhandle.aspx).

Pay close attention to creation and destruction of HWND. Responsibility for object destruction is unusual in .Net and is in general a source for bugs and memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

That would be IntPtr, which is meant to contain unmanaged handles and pointers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx

Answer (score 3):

HWND as was stated is an abbreviation for Window Handle. real type behind HWND is just a structure with an integer field. So it's analog in .Net is IntPtr

However here a quite interesting question - What the size of HWND in x64 Windows. Because IntPtr from .net then have 64 bit long. But if HWND remain 32 bit long there maybe problems

Comment: The type behind HWND is not the struct, but a pointer to the struct HWND__. This is to get a "typesafe" pointer sized type. To get the value out of IntPtr you should use IntPtr.ToPointer().

Answer (score 1):

[IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx). Also you might read about [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) calls.

Answer (score 1):

HWND is similar to IntPtr.

use the following syntax

```
    [DllImport("ImortingDllName.dll")]
    public static extern void ExposedFunction(IntPtr hwndmsg, int all);
```